# Counting several instances of the same word from a text file

Tags: python

Complete beginner, searched a lot of threads but couldn't find a solution that fits me.

I have a text file, python_examples.txt which contains some words. On line four, the word hello appears twice in a row, like "hello hello".

My code is supposed to find the word the user inputs and count how many times it appears, it works but as I said, not if the same word appears multiple times on the same row. So there are 2 hellos on line 4 and one on line 13 but it only finds a total of 2 hellos. Fixes? Thanks,

```
user_input = input("Type in the word you are searching for: ")

word_count = 0
line_count = 0

with open ("python_example.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1
        if user_input in line:

            word_count += 1
            print("found " + user_input + " on line " + str(line_count))
        else:
            print ("nothing on line " + str(line_count))

print ("\nfound a total of " + str(word_count) + " words containing " + "'" + user_input + "'")
```

Comment: Can you share the text file? Also, are you aware of the usual caveats regarding `string in substring` (`"hell"` appears twice in the line `"hello hello"`, which is not what us humans mean when we say that a word appears in a sentence)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
word_count += line.count(user_input)
```

instead of :

```
word_count += 1
```

it will count all appearance of `user_input` in the file line

Comment: @Bobosen  If this fixes your issue you can accept the answer, thx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with these two lines:

```py
if user_input in line:
    word_count += 1
```

You increase the count by 1 if the input appears on the line, regardless of whether it appears more than once.

---

This should do the job:

```py
user_input = input("Type in the word you are searching for: ")

word_count = 0

with open("python_example.txt") as f:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        line_inp_count = line.count(user_input)
        if line_inp_count:
            word_count += line_inp_count
            print(f"input {user_input} appears {line_inp_count} time(s) on line {line_num}")
        else:
            print(f"nothing on line {line_num}")

print(f"the input appeared a total of {word_count} times in {line_num} lines.")
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is use a library to parse the words in your text file rather than iterating one line at a time. There are several classes in [`nltk.tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) which are easy to use.

```py
import nltk.tokenize.regexp


def count_word_in_file(filepath, word):
    """Give the number for times word appears in text at filepath."""
    tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.regexp.WordPunctTokenizer()
    with open(filepath) as f:
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(f.read())
    return tokens.count(word)
```

This handles awkward cases like the substring 'hell' appearing in 'hello' as mentioned in a comment, and is also a route towards case-insenstive matching, stemming, and other refinements.